# Create an #hashtag link from a string, except HEX color

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, hashtag

I've got a small issue with this function.

I have to turn every #hashtags in a link, but because my text is in html, it's turning in a link hex color as well:

```
$string = "<span style="color:#fff">Stackoverflow is the best #website in the world</span> #stack #cool <span style="background-color:#666;">Signature</span> bla bla bla..";

function hashtag($string) {
    $input = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)#([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '<a style="background-color:#EAE2F3; text-decoration:none;" href="/mypage.php?ht=$1">#$1</a>', $string);
    return $input;
}
```

How can I get a work around?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is it converting that it shouldn't?

Comment: Your function is ok. Use $string = strip_tags($string) before call your function and that's it ;)

Comment: The result is that even #fffff turned in a link.

<span style="color:<a href='myhashtaglink'>#fff</a>">.....

Comment: The fact is that my function turn in a link everything has an hashtag #, hex code as well. But I need to avoid it. Thanks!

Comment: So if in an element it should be ignored or what is pattern you want? Example looks like it functions correctly https://3v4l.org/0oJBN

Comment: Yes, it could be an idea ignore if that is inside an element.
The example looks like nice!

Comment: I've got where the problem is. I actually have the style inline with a "space":
-> <span style="color: #fff"> in this way the script replace the hex color.
-> <span style="color:#fff"> in this way it doesn't.

How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Work Around but I don't like it so much:

[code]
function hashtag($string) {
 $string =  str_ireplace("color: #", "color:#", $string);
 $input = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)#([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '<a style="background-color:#EAE2F3; text-decoration:none;" href="/listato.php?ht=$1">#$1</a>', $string);
 return $input;
}

$string = "#stayathome fight the coronavirus now .....&#9742;&#12826... #comeon <span style="background-color:#666;">other stuff</span>";
[/code]

Even because if the hashtag is located at the start of the string, it don't get replaced.